# Bash script loop break even with true statement

Tags: shell, loops, sh

I'm trying to run some commands in two system state, while screen is on do something and when screen goes off do something else and do these statements every time. I've found this method but this only runs awake_state once and never goes to sleep_state check or back to awake_state again. I debugged by adding "echo state >> log_file_path;" in these two statements.

```
#!/sbin/busybox sh

AWAKE_STATE()
{
echo 50 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness;
}

SLEEP_STATE()
{
echo 80 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness;
}

background_process=1;

if [ "$background_process" -eq "1" ]; then
(while true; do
    while [ "$(cat /sys/module/lm3697/parameters/sleep_state)" -ne "0" ]; do
        # when screen goes on it will pass.
        sleep "3";
    done;
    AWAKE_STATE;

    while [ "$(cat /sys/module/lm3697/parameters/sleep_state)" -ne "1" ]; do
        # when screen goes off it will pass.
        sleep "3";
    done;
    SLEEP_STATE;
done &);
fi;
```

The `/sys/module/lm3697/parameters/sleep_state` indicate screen status and the `background_process=1` created with another process to switch this script on and it doesn't change until i change it (it's always on). `sleep_state=1` means the screen is off.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to terminate your lines with `;` in bash (except when you write several instructions on the same line, like `while something; do`)

Comment: Why are you running the entire loop inside brackets?

Comment: i thought it means don't go to another command until finish this one.so i will remove those

Comment: Are you running the script and expecting it to change things in the shell running it?

Comment: to check the status. is it false? what is the solution ?

Comment: Also this is tagged as `bash` but you are using `sh`

Comment: yes. i expect change things in these two state

Comment: does it correct to run in #!/bin/bash

Comment: @MostafaZarghami Probably not, I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to do though, hopefully someone else will be able to help, good luck.

Comment: @123 thank you, BTW i added my commands to awake and sleep state.